# Map function over values of dict in ansible jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, python-3.5, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I want to convert the values of a dictionary into strings and lowercase them, then map over the dict to join each item pair with an `=`, and then join the items with a `,`.

Example input:

```
{"A": "Aardvark", "B": "Beaver", "C": "Cat"}
```

Desired output:

```
A=aardvark,B=beaver,C=cat
```

I actually don't care about the order that A, B, C arrive in, but I want to make sure that I the keys and values don't get mixed up in the end, i.e., no `A=cat` or whatever.

What I'm doing now is this:

```
{{ foo.keys() | zip(foo.values() | map("lower")) | map("join", "=") | join(",") }}
```

It works so far with the test data I have given it. However, I am not sure that this is guaranteed to be correct, nor do I think this is the most efficient or elegant way to solve this. **Is there a better way** to map the `lower` function over the values in the dict?

I tried using `dict2items` and specifying an `attribute` on the `map` function, but I get an error about an unexpected keyword arg when I do this, plus it's really ugly:

```
{{ (foo | dict2items | map("lower", attribute="value") | list | items2dict).items() | map("join", "=") | join(",") }}
```

*Note: I am using Ansible 2.9 on Python 3.5 right now, but would really like a solution that works regardless of the Python version.*

Comment: I believe your use of `zip` is the best you're going to get due to the requirement to lowercase the values; you're also always welcome to use the imperative version `{% for ... %}` because the version of jinja2 used by ansible isn't very "functional programming" friendly, as you've experienced. Sometimes the imperative version is much, much clearer, even when more verbose

Comment: @mdaniel I considered it, but doing comma-separated values like that is always a pain

Comment: @2rs2ts dont forget to close this old question by validating the answer please

Comment: @Frenchy I didn't use your solution so I didn't validate that it was correct. I will just trust that it works, since in the almost 2 years since I asked this question, I learned more about ansible, and at a glance, it seems like it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom filter.

Create a `filter_plugins/` folder in your playbook folder (I have named the file `myfilters.py` and the filter `cstring`)

`myfilters.py` in folder `filter_plugins/`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'cstring': self.cstring
        }
    
    def cstring(self, data):
        result = ""
        for k in data:
            result += (',' if result else '') + k + '=' + data[k].lower()
    
        return result
```

playbook:

```yaml
- name: "tips1"
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    foo: {"A": "Aardvark", "B": "Beaver", "C": "Cat"}
  tasks:
    - name: debug users      
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ foo | cstring }}"
  
    - name: display result     
      debug:
        var: result
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": "A=aardvark,B=beaver,C=cat"
}
```

The advantage of using a custom filter is to do complex things or lot of operations with only one action.